# How to use non-default browser?

Tags: r

I have an R package that triggers Oauth2 flow in the browser (via `httr`). A user is in the odd situation that their IT department requires a specific system default browser (in this case, it's IE + Windows). But the user needs to do the OAuth in a different browser.

I am aware of the `R_BROWSER` environment variable and would like to temporarily set it to the browser of need. (And then hope that will be honoured in the OAuth flow...)

I am fiddling with this on a Mac and my default browser is Safari. My usual situation wrt `R_BROWSER` is this

```r
Sys.getenv("R_BROWSER")
#> [1] "/usr/bin/open"
```

I know how to force the use of, e.g., Chrome from the shell or, from R, with a `system()` call:

```r
system("/usr/bin/open -a '/Applications/Google Chrome.app' 'http://slate.com'")
```

But how do I transfer that knowledge to an appropriate setting for `R_BROWSER`? This does not work:

```r
Sys.setenv("R_BROWSER" = "/usr/bin/open -a '/Applications/Google Chrome.app'")
```

When I subsequently `browseURL()`, the usual Safari default gets used. I suspect the answer differs by OS. For Mac OS, it seems desirable to avoid using `open` and somehow specify the browser directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you should also save the previous values of both `browser` option and `R_BROWSER` so that you can restore the previous state of the session:

```
old_R_BROWSER <- Sys.getenv("R_BROWSER")
old_browser <- options()$browser
```

Then you can achieve desired behaviour by re-running the command **@Hack-R** posted after setting `R_BROWSER`.

```
Sys.setenv("R_BROWSER" = "/usr/bin/open -a '/Applications/Safari.app'")
options(browser = as.vector(Sys.getenv("R_BROWSER")))
browseURL("http://www.google.com") # opens in Safari, though my default is Chrome
```

(You can also just directly set `options(browser = "/usr/bin/open -a '/Applications/Safari.app'")` and `browseURL` works.)

Finally, restore the system state

```
Sys.setenv("R_BROWSER" = old_R_BROWSER)
options(browser = old_browser)
```

Answer (score 3):

R looks for the browser specified at configure time.

The default setting of options("browser") is set to be

```
options(browser = as.vector(Sys.getenv("R_BROWSER")))
```

and the browser found at configure time is set in the R_BROWSER variable 
in the file etc/Renviron.  So edit that file.

Finally, if this is a shared system, you can have the following in your
~/.Renviron file

```
R_BROWSER=${R_BROWSER-'FireFox'}
```

See `?Startup`.  (You could also use the Rprofile files, but people normally 
only have one .Renviron file.)

I base this on [this](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2003-August/037484.html).

Comment: Yes I read the thing you link to before I posted. Have you been able to use this information to get R to use, e.g., Chrome on a Mac?